# android no compatible devices found

Tags: android, driver, device

I've just installed the android sdk with eclipse and imported a project. but when i try to run it on my phone it doesn't run "no compatible devices" error is displayed.

a generic "android" device is displayed under "other devices" in manage devices and there's the error icon saying that there's no driver installed, if i try to install google usb driver it says that no compatible driver where found. it's strange because i've other 2 pcs and the phone works well. obviously usb debugging is turned on.

min target:8 , max: 18 , phone: 4.1.2

any idea?

Comment: Have you installed your device driver?

Comment: yes it's showed in device manager and my computer with the correct name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually happen when Eclipse does not found Andriod Debug Bridge(adb) somehow.

So, in order to sort out this problem you can download "Universal adb".

Its a software which installs adb required for compatibility between your device and Eclipse IDE.

First you just need to connect your device with your laptop and run the Universal adb software. Hit the install button. And its all done.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It happens from time-to-time with Eclipse.

Try restarting Eclipse and if it doesn't help restart your system