# Connect Galaxy Ace gt-s5830 in developer mode Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, android-studio, usb-debugging

I've installed Android studio on my home PC (running with windows 7 Professional), and tried to
use my Mobile Phone (Glalaxy Ace gt-s5830) for developement. Problem here is that neither android studio nor adb-tools find my device. I enabled USB-Debugging ofc, I have downloaded the USB-Driver from the sdk-studio-extras and tried to manually install my device following this: [usb drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

I searched for drivers specific for my device and found only KIES, and unfortunatly, this works like crap. Most versions of it won't even start, those that do don't do anything (every option I got either fails or feel like the buttons have no function at all).

The device itself is working fine on my Macs and Linux OS at work. What do I need to do get android studio to recognize it as a device to choose from?

Comment: You can try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861155/android-no-compatible-devices-found/21861281#21861281

Comment: tried it and it makes no difference, still can't find the device

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I have the same problem.